# Automator not working with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, automator

I am trying to use automomator to control my UI and Google Chrome, but after recording my actions (watch me do) and then replaying them, I get the error "application chrome is not running when it is expected to."

Chrome is definitely running, as I just used it to record the automator actions. I am just wondering how I will be able to use Automator with Google Chrome :)

Cheers

Answer (score 30):

I was having a similar problem, here's what I did to 'seemingly' solve it. Perhaps you can give it a try.

1. Record your action as usual.
2. In the 'Watch me do' box, click and hold on the action, then drag it below the 'Watch me do' box.

This will convert the action to AppleScript - which then the automation worked for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Also, if you have more than one action, just hold down shift to select them all and drag down and run that.

Comment: Or press cmd + A in the Event list.